# Aggregate based on flag (with qualifiers)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert some calculated fields in Hyperion Studio to SQL. I got stuck trying to aggregate enrollment counts based on a shared course location/date/time. I have a flag created using LEAD to mark rows where the course location is identical to the row below. I need to roll up those consecutive rows, based on the flag, to get a total enrollment count for each location. The flag calculation includes exceptions (seen in example below, rows 2 and 3) where I specifically command it not to flag despite a shared location.

This is an example of base data that includes the flag (Roll Up is the field I'm trying to calculate):

```
SectionID     Course Name   Title   Instructor  Location    Enrollment  Flag    Roll Up
1             EN.100.201    Title1   Prof. W    Building 1   16     
2             EN.550.365    Title2   Prof. X    Building 2   5      
3             EN.530.403    Title3   Prof. Y    Building 2   30     
4             EN.400.401    Title4   Prof. Z    Building 3   25          Y  
5             EN.400.601    Title4   Prof. Z    Building 3   10
```

Here is the output I'm trying to achieve

```
SectionID     Course Name   Title   Instructor  Location    Enrollment  Flag    Roll Up
1             EN.100.201    Title1  Prof. W     Building 1   16                 16
2             EN.550.365    Title2  Prof. X     Building 2   5                  5
3             EN.530.403    Title3  Prof. Y     Building 2   30                 30
5             EN.400.601    Title4  Prof. Z     Building 3   10                 35
```

Thanks in advance! Edit: made this easier to read; sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: Do not use images to show your code/tables. Please add the data as text.

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt!

Comment: `WHERE BY` gets executed before `GROUP BY`. Removing specific rows in the manner of `WHERE CourseName NOT IN (EN.200.205)` will work perfectly with a subsequent `GROUP BY`. Are there any other reasons to not do a simple aggregation?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeMenoutis, I believe the reason I can't use GROUP BY is because I have to select all fields in the dataset to include in the output and they differ on multiple fields (ID, course name). If I use GROUP BY I have to include all fields I'm selecting in the clause, which would split out all the unique rows instead of rolling up by shared location. (Right?)

Comment: Your example is covered by using `group by Location`, and as for the fields, 1) In the Z case, you merged 401 and 601. I'm not sure why, but this is aggregation logic. Maybe the maximum value? Same for title and instructor. Enrollment is, of course, the sum.